# How to apply stroke to a button specific sides in android

Tags: android, layer-list

How can I apply stroke to a button's only two sides that is LEFT border and RIGHT border? in android.

I have apply the following code but it's not working

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- This is the main color -->
<item>
      <shape>
            <solid android:color="#EEEEEE" />
      </shape>
</item>

<!-- This is the line -->
<item android:right="1dp">
     <shape>
           <solid android:color="#333333" />
     </shape>
</item>

<item android:left="1dp">
    <shape >
        <solid android:color="#333333"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Dear! now you can see my code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were on the right track.  This will do the trick:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
          <shape>
                <solid android:color="#EEEEEE" />
          </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- This is the line -->
    <item android:right="1dp" android:left="1dp">
         <shape>
               <solid android:color="#333333" />
         </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

And use this as the background for your button.  Just tested it - works just fine.

Comment: ever managed to use something like this in conjunction with a background selector?

Comment: seems you can either specify which borders to set or have a background selector. combining both seems to cancel out the selector....

Comment: i solved this by setting the layer-list border on a parent, then a background drawable selector on a 'fill parent' child, with margin on the child equivalent to the parents border width. other wise they over lap as the border seems to be on the inside.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a 9-patch drawable that looks like this:

[image]

It has the required black border, 1px on each side of the 0x333 color and the rest is filled with 0xeee. 9-patches scale with the size of the view that they are applied to. So you can use it as a background or src